# clang-format defaults to not format if no style file found

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, clang-format

I am working with some repos where no `.clang-format` style file is provided, in this case`I have to disable auto-formatting in vscode to avoid`clang-format` nuking the entire file.

Is it possible to have it default to doing nothing if no valid `.clang-format` file is found? I tried accomplishing this but couldn't find a solution, my current settings look something like

```
...
    "clang-format.fallbackStyle": "none",
    "clang-format.style": "file",
    "clang-format.executable": "/usr/bin/clang-format",
    "clang-format.language.c.enable": true,
    "clang-format.language.cpp.enable": true,
    "[cpp]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "xaver.clang-format",
    },
...
```